# Integrate $\oint_c \frac{z^2sinz}{4z^2-1}dz$ C the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Using the residue theorem, first find the poles, $4z^2-1=0$, $z=\pm. \frac{1}{2}$. Both poles are inside the unit circle, so:
$Res_{z=\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{z^2sinz}{4z^2-1})=\frac{1}{16}sin\frac{1}{2}$
$Res_{z=\frac{-1}{2}}(\frac{z^2sinz}{4z^2-1})=\frac{1}{16}sin\frac{1}{2}$
$2\pi i(\frac{1}{16}sin\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{16}sin\frac{1}{2})=\frac{\pi i}{4}sin{\frac{1}{2}}$

Looking for any feedback... Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to know how to proceed? or just check what you have done so far is correct? It is correct by the way

Comment: I thought that was it..., but yes, if there's another step, please advise

Comment: ... and you are done!